# How to save photos from iCloud to external hardrive

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, iphone

My iCloud is full and i would like to move the photos from my icloud on my macbook to my external hardrive. I do not have a desktop or WINDOWS

Answer (score 1):

In OS X Mountain Lion or later

1.Open Photos and select the Shared tab.

2.Double-click a shared stream.

3.Right-click (or Control-click) a photo and choose Import.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I would download photos right from iCloud in web browser directly to external drive.

And then would remove all photos on iCloud. This can be managed completely from the web app at https://www.icloud.com/#photos